# how to prevent css and js being cached by internet service provider?

Tags: css, caching

I got "dump" isp that always cached internet pages and its css for at least 1 day. 
Although the css / js in the server changed, the presented css are not changed (i have been clear my cache everytime)

how to "tell" my isp not to cache some files like css and js ?

thank you !!

at the moment: i'm using proxy to check a under developed web so that it don't get cached ..

Comment: that's not about isp cache, it's all about browser cache and you can simply ctrl + f5 your page for yourself and/or add "?v=xxx" in front of your file address for everyone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way Stack Overflow itself solves this problem is to add a version parameter to the CSS and JS URLs, which refer to the version of the referenced files:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=4542">
```

Every time the referenced files change, the href attribute of the link tag is updated in the HTML code, thus supporting caching *and* updated referenced files.

Comment: How do you programmatically retrieve the version you want of that referenced file?  Subversion keywords only refer to the file you are currently in.

Comment: Instead of using a version number, you can use the "last modified" timestamp of the file your serving.  Thus, the file is cached, but once you modify the file clients will not use the old cached copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to append some random string to every request of an external file like:

```
<link href="/css/style.css?cachekiller=1337" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

where the 1337 in the above code should be generated randomly for every request e.g.

```
<?php time() ?>
```

or something

Answer (score 0):

You can include these documents directly in your HTML files, between `<script>` or `<style>` tags. It will obviously make all your HTML files bigger, but that's basically what you're asking.

It's the only way you can be 100% sure that your CSS and JS is not cached at all.